# docker-compose volumes not mounting to host directories

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose for deployment, with a 2 `docker-compose.yml` setup where I'm building the image locally and pulling from docker hub on the server.

Besides building vs pulling an image, the volumes config is the same.

Locally:

```
app:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - "/data/volume:/volume"
```

And on the server:

```
app:
  image: username/repo:tag
  volumes:
    - "/data/volume:/volume"
```

In my Dockerfile:

```
volume /volume
```

Locally my volume mounts to the specified directory fine, with files created by the app persisted there outside the container.  On the deployment server, however, this does not happen.

Files **are** however created and persisted through deploys, even though my deployment script runs `docker-compose down -v` which presumably removes named & anonymous volumes on the container.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see what.  Could it be a caching issue?  The volume configuration was not the same on initial deploy.

### More Info:

I actually can't seem to **force** the images to be lost between deploys.  I ran:

```
docker-compose down -v --rmi all --remove-orphans
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

... which I thought would leave me with a clean slate for redeploying, then:

```
docker pull username/repo:tag
docker-compose build --no-cache --force-rm
docker-compose up -d
```

... and the files which are supposed to be in the mounted volume are **still there**, and there's still nothing in the mounted dir on the disk.  Any ideas?

### Still more info

Running `docker inspect <container>` on the server yields a mount configuration like this:

```
"Mounts": [
  "Source": "/data/volume",
  "Destination": "/volume",
  "Mode": "rw",
  "RW": true,
  "Propagation": "rprivate"
]
```

I notice there's no Driver specified, and not sure about the significance of "rprivate", but the Source and Destination do appear to be correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was that I'd mounted a EBS volume to `/volume` **after** the Docker service had been started.

The directory was mounted in the container, which is why the `docker inspect` looks correct, but it mounted the pre-existing mount point which was overlayed by the host's own mount.

This mount happened after the Docker service was started, but long before any containers were actually started up, so it didn't occur to me that Docker might not be respecting the filesystem change which had happened earlier.

The solution was just to restart the Docker service.

Answer (score 6):

Just want to add that if you're developing on **Windows**, you should explicitly allow Docker to access your C: drive. Until you do that, any mapped volumes will appear as empty.

If running via Hyper-V (Docker for Windows):

- Go to Settings -> Shared Drives, check "C:"    ([source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/06/14/configuring-docker-for-windows-volumes/))

If running via VirtualBox:

- `VBoxManage sharedfolder add default --name c --hostpath /c --automount` ([source](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3908))

Comment: I had to click "Reset Credentials" under Shared Drives to get this working. This might be required if you change your user account settings, or switch between a Local and Microsoft account.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest on the server check the permissions on /data/volume change them to 777 temporary for testing if this is the issue. Also user server is just a Linux machine? Or is a virtualized environment created with docker-machine or something like that.

The volumes you are using are not anonymous or named but host mounted. There is no command in docker which will delete a host mounted volume.

I also suggest to do the same procedure using `docker run` instead `docker-compose` to discard a problem with docker-compose

Regards

Comment: Host is just a linux machine.  Re: the deleting the volumes, I don't expect docker to delete files off the host machine, but that's what I'm not understanding.  The files are not in the `/data/volume` directory which I specified as the source for the mount.  So I'm assuming that mount configuration didn't take, and that the files are actually in an anonymous docker volume, or something...  The permissions on the mount directory are 777 already, should have mentioned that.

Comment: When you say the files persists between redeploys. Is that in local environment your application write the files. You push the image to registry then pull in server. And then u issue a docker exec bash and see the files there? Doblecheck with docker images in local and server you are using the same images.

Comment: No the images on the server were uploaded there and never existed locally.  If I docker exec into a container shell I can see that the images exist in the volume at the specified mount point, but they are not reflected outside the volume on the host.  And yet, after deleting all containers, images, volumes and redeploying, the images reappear inside the container.  So that's the other half of my confusion here.  1 obviously why it's not working, but 2, if these images are surviving between deploys, where are they?

Comment: Well recently something very strange happened to me with networking and docker-compose. Could you please try upgrading your docker-compose.yml to version: '2'? This little change fixed the things for me. Also check you are using latest docker-compose version and latest docker version.

Comment: One more thing. What happen when you replicate the docker-compose.yml using docker run -v /data/volume:/volume. Same behavior ? I suggest try this first to see if the problem is with docker-compose

Comment: I am using version 2, sorry, I omitted that part from the xample.  Good idea to try to run without compose.  I'll try that shortly.

Answer (score 1):

### Windows 11 - wsl 2

I was having issue when adding `volume` (both via cli, Dockerfile, docker-compose)
So for instance

```
version: '3'

services:
  myserver:
    restart: unless-stopped  
    volumes:
      - "./app:/app"
```

It was not creating the volume, I could testing by running in the dockerfile this

```
FROM python:3.7-buster

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

CMD ["ls", "/app","-lah"]
```

Which would show just an empty result when running

```
docker-compose up
```

The solution to use **absolute imports instead of relative** in the volume declaration so that the final docker-compose would like as this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  myserver:
    restart: unless-stopped  
    volumes:
      - "home/user/app:/app"
```